# Getting the right stack trace out of jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, jestjs, stack-trace

I am currently debugging some tests written with jest over typescript and I'm having a bit of a headache.

If a test, or tested class, runs Postgres SQL and there is an error in the query, I get the wrong stack trace, for example, this:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""0""
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/sklivvz/src/xxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/sklivvz/src/xxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/sklivvz/src/xxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/sklivvz/src/xxx/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:314:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

The "error" line is very useful, however, the stack trace only tells me that the error was thrown by the pg-protocol driver. I would like to know which line within *my code* generated the error.

I am exactly 82.7% sure that this is due to PG's `query` being async.

It is incredibly time-consuming having to step debug or (gasp) `console.log` my way to each error when it would only be a matter of showing the correct call stack in order to make it better.

Has anyone found a way of making this developer-friendly?

Comment: are you allowed to update the implementation instead of jest tests? such as postgres.query().catch(error =>).

Comment: The stacktrace happening to be this way is not because of Jest, but because of Postgres lib's callback. The error is created somewhere inside the package `pg-protocol` which is also before your callback. To have a stacktrace of your code, you have to catch, and throw your own error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is related to [`brianc/node-postgres` issue 2484](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2484)

> is (there) a preferred package, extension, or method for providing more detail when you get a syntax error back from the parser?
> (for instance, one that listed line number, column of the error)
>
> for instance, right now:
>
> ```
> error: syntax error at or near "as"
>    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/collspec/projects/staff-portal/sprint-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
> ```
>
> desired behavior:
>
> ```sh
> error: syntax error at or near "as", line 5, column 7
>    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/collspec/projects/staff-portal/sprint-server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
> ```

[Possible workaround](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2484#issuecomment-790914020) from that issue:

> There are a bunch of additional fields on Error objects populated by the driver.
> If you log the error object you can see them. They correspond to the [error fields returned by the server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-error-fields.html):
>
> For example with the command:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT foo
> FROM bar
> ```
>
> You can get an error like this:
>
> ```json
> {
>  length: 102,
>  severity: 'ERROR',
>  code: '42P01',
>  detail: undefined,
>  hint: undefined,
>  position: '17',
>  internalPosition: undefined,
>  internalQuery: undefined,
>  where: undefined,
>  schema: undefined,
>  table: undefined,
>  column: undefined,
>  dataType: undefined,
>  constraint: undefined,
>  file: 'parse_relation.c',
>  line: '1180',
>  routine: 'parserOpenTable'
> }
> ```
>
> The one you want is position. It gives you the character offset in the SQL of the error.
> In this example the position value of "17" refers to the start of the bar token in the SQL.
> It's not always populated though as it depends on what caused the error (generally just parse errors).

Comment: Thank you - the problem is not in the accuracy of the position of the syntax error in the SQL, but the fact that jest eats up _where the script itself is located_. If you have hundreds of SQL scripts and the error is "Error near SELECT", it's not very useful :-D

Comment: @Sklivvz OK, too bad. I was trying to counter the Tumbleweed effect you mentioned yesterday (https://twitter.com/sklivvz/status/1417761292627152900)

Comment: Thanks, I totally appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with aws-sdk for DynamoDb. This is a stacktrace I usually get from aws-sdk.

```
ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
at Request.extractError (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:52:27)
at Request.callListeners (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
at Request.transition (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
at D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
at Request.callListeners (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

My workaround is simply to catch async errors, and overwrite their stack traces. On the other hand, you may append Postgres stacktrace, or error message to your own errors.

```
  async function getPersonFromDb (personId: string): Promise<DocumentClient.AttributeMap | undefined> {
    const result = await documentClient.get({ // Similar to postgres.query()
      TableName: 'wrong-name',
      Key: { pk: personId, sk: personId }
    }).promise().catch(error => {
      Error.captureStackTrace(error)
      throw error
    })
    return result.Item
  }

  test('Get a person from DynamoDB', async () => {
    const person = await getPersonFromDb('hello')
    expect(person).not.toBeUndefined()
  })


// ========= new stacktrace ========
Error: Requested resource not found
    at D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\test\abc.test.ts:12:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at getPersonFromDb (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\test\abc.test.ts:8:20) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspaces\typescript-starters\console-app\test\abc.test.ts:18:20) // my code, and where my error is thrown
```